# Nightwatch JS page object returns undefined

Tags: selenium, mocha.js, nightwatch.js

I'm using Nightwatch with mocha.

I try to get an element's text from the page object. When trying to compare the received text to another text I receive an error "AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'Text'".

This is the Page Object function:

```
const Commands = {

  getInstanceLabel() {
    this.getText('.DropdownSelect__label', (result) => {
      return result.value;
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the Test code:

```
it('Should sort the collection in ascending order by default', (client) => {
  const labelText = client.page.instanceCollectionPage().getInstanceLabel();
  expect(labelText).to.equal('Text');
});
```

Why is this showing undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you are using arrow functions, and as mentioned in mdn:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function
>   expressions and **does not bind its own this**, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

You can fix it in two different ways:

### using function:

e.g. (you can use **this**)

```
  it('Should launch', function (browser) {
    const url = browser.launchUrl;
    browser.url(url).waitForElementVisible('body', 1000);    
    browser.getText('#txtWelcome', function (result) {
      this.verify.equal(result.value, 'Welcome');
    });
  });
```

## using browser:

e.g. (you need to access the browser object direcly)

```
  it('Should launch', (browser) => {
    const url = browser.launchUrl;
    browser.url(url).waitForElementVisible('body', 1000);    
    browser.getText('#txtWelcome', (result) => {
      browser.verify.equal(result.value, 'Welcome');
    });
  });
```

Those are just examples on how to use **this**, I can not provide more details on your issue because you don't show what *InstanceCollection* does.

Comment: The InstanceCollection is just a call to the client.page.instanceCollection page object. I'll edit the question.